# URL rewrite hacking attempt?

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I have a re-write URL on an Nginx server in the form of the following:

```
/title-xx/ /getTitle.php?title=xx
```

And the method used is:

```
$titles->getTitleDetails( xx );
```

Now what I've recently spotted from access logs is somehow someone has managed to find out the method name and has been plugging it into the URL request:

```
/title-'.%20$titles-%3EgetTitleDetails()%20.'/nameofmovie.html
```

I'm guessing the site might have been edited live at some point and an error message exposed what the function name was but, what I'm puzzled about is what do they have to gain by making it part of the URL request.

Is there a certain type of attack I should watch out for?

Comment: If your function does not sanitize the user input before accessing your database they can go wild and even delete all your database.

Comment: I highly doubt it is an attack, the person that was editing live probably generated that URL in the error message. If you have people editing files on a production site (sin number one), at the very least turn off display_errors (sin number two).